# Is it possible to add my custom JS file so page DOM could access it?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The problem now is that if I add some DOM elements I must put all JS inside tags creating huge mess in code for example:

```html
<div onclick='//js monstrous oneliner with function declarations and so on..
              //that must be repeated many times multipcating the whole mess..
  '>
 Here some pure html thing.
</div>
```

So can I add my custom JS file into rendered document in the same way as I'm able to add DOM elements ?

Comment: Why not just add onclick listener to this div?

Comment: serg: because the JavaScript context is different—you won't be able to see the function the onclick handler wants to call.

Comment: @Dominic I meant `el.addEventListener("click", my_function, false);`, not `<div onclick="my_function()">`. Content scripts can listen to events just fine, and it is much cleaner solution than injecting script imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject a JavaScript file from your extension into the page.  Then, the onclick handler can refer to that directly.

Assume you have a script in your extension:

```js
// myfile.js
function hello() {
  alert('hello world');
}
```

In your content script, make the script tag:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = chrome.extension.getURL('/myfile.js');
```

Now, you can write your HTML like this:

```html
<div onclick="hello">…</div>
```

Note that because the content script doesn't run in the same JavaScript context as the page, doing this **won't** work from your content extension.

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.onclick = someFuncInMyExtension;
```

Comment: one liner: `document.createElement('script').src = chrome.extension.getURL('/func.js');`

Comment: Thanks that worked for me, but I had to add `"web_accessible_resources": [ "myfile.js" ]` to manifest.json.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's quite simple: see this document just to have an idea http://blog.jeffhaynie.us/cross-browser-way-to-dynamically-load-javascript.html